# Validating form with the foreign key relation

Tags: symfony, symfony-forms, symfony-validator

My database schema is something like this:

```
create table users (
  id INT PRIMARY KEY,
  username TEXT,
)

create table posts (
  id INT PRIMARY KEY,
  user_id INT,
  title TEXT,
  content TEXT,
)
```

i am developing api to create "posts" , so i am posting like below and the relation has been defined in User and Posts entity

```
{
   "user": {
        "username": "some_name"
   },
   "title": "testing",
   "content": "test content"
}
```

and i need to validate whether correct username is posted?. How could i do that?

My controller like this

```
$post = new Post();
$form = $this->createForm(PostType::class, $post);
$form->submit($request->request->all());
```

My builder Form like this

```
$builder
    ->add('title', TextType::class)
    ->add('content', TextType::class)
    ->add('User', UserType::class, array(
        'data_class' => User::class
    ));
```

But it tries to create user everytime instead of checking valid username is passed. Any ideas?

Comment: you want to check if the user exist before persist data (post) ?

Comment: @MohammedYassineCHABLI   i want to check valid username is posted, if so persist data into the "posts" table with their corresponding user id else show some error

Comment: what do you mean by valid username ? you mean if the user exist un user table , is that ?

Comment: yes @MohammedYassineCHABLI

Answer (score 0):

Let's suppose your User entity named **User** ,inside the bundle named **App**, the property  nammed  **username** in the Entity **User** in your controller  :

```
$user = $em->getRepository('AppBundle:User')->findBy(array('username' => $username)); // we suppose that you have already extract the value of username from the request into $username.
```

And then you can just check :

```
if($user instanceof User){
// do whatever you need here 
}
```

Comment: Is it possible to do this in form builder 
` $builder
    ->add('title', TextType::class)
    ->add('content', TextType::class)
    ->add('User', UserType::class, array(
        'data_class' => User::class
    ));'
instead of controller

Comment: you want to add that inside your form builder ?

Comment: yes , the relation has already defined inside the entity, so through form builder i need to add

Comment: you can pass the value trought the $options of the form builder

Comment: createForm(string $type, mixed $data = null, array $options = array()) // the third param

Comment: that help you  ?

Comment: In my POST entity, i have defined the property as "user" which points to User entity, so am posting like this "user": {   "username": "some_name"  } . i like to validate and fetch the user id inside the form builder automatically based on the relation instead of separate query to manually fetch based on passed username and pass it through options.

Comment: i hope someway we can achieve this

Comment: i don't undertand what you are trying to say